# Position image ( or some other point ) with x and y params

Tags: android, xamarin, ibeacon

Im making a android app thats getting `x` and `y` params from the red dots(iBeacons). the blue dot should represent you. I have the trilateration algoritm. Im just having some problems positioning the blue dot with the params I get(even if I hard code the values like below:

```
var b1 = new iBeacon();
        var b2 = new iBeacon();
        var b3 = new iBeacon();

        b1.X = 200;
        b1.Y = 100;

        b2.X = 290;
        b2.Y = 520;

        b3.X = 20;
        b3.Y = 1000;

        var curPos = TR.Trilaterate(b1,b2,b3);
```

[image: http://imgur.com/4wtULUr]